# What are some resources to learn Probability, Statistics and Stochastic Processes so I can understand Optimal State Estimation?

Tags: kalman-filter, sensor-fusion, estimation, uncertainty, statistics

I went to grad school for Mechanical Engineering almost 7 years ago, where I avoided any probability/stats coursework like plague and stuck to linear algebra and differential equations for my math course requirements. All I had was an intro to probability course and a course in random variables in college.

My current job requires me to understand the mathematical basis for State Estimation so I can implement and tune recursive estimators like the Kalman Filter, particle filter etc to try out various IMU & GNSS data fusion approaches. To that end, I tried going through the book **Optimal State Estimation by Dan Simon** and realized I need to pick up **multivariate distributions, statistics and stochastic processes** before I can tackle the material in OSE.

I was able to easily find and use resources to pick up multivariate probability distributions.

1. **Statistics**- But my lack of familiarity with the entire area of statistics is keeping me from being able to decide on resources to learn it from. Most stats books seem to be geared towards analyzing large data sets in psych, sociology or biology

   But I think the stats that I need to know has to do with high frequency data across time  from one or two sources with only a few variables which are interrelated (pose, velocity, acceleration)

   Please excuse my ignorance on this topic but I hope I'm articulating my confusion here clearly enough. But are there any resources for this "type"/subset of statistics? Can you also please recommend a book/video play list for self-study that emphasizes clarity and intuitive understanding over rigor?
2. **Stochastic Processes**- I have not had any coursework in this one either. Are there any resources suitable for self-study, that will then help me make sense of stochastic modelling involved in state estimation?

Comment: So your only knowledge gap is the statistics related to the subject? So you are familiar with state space models (discrete and/or continues time)?

Comment: Yes, I've had course work in digital(discrete time) control systems which is almost entirely state space modeling.